# Define function in unix/linux command line (e.g. BASH)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Sometimes I have a one-liner that I am repeating many times for a particular task, but will likely never use again in the exact same form. It includes a file name that I am pasting in from a directory listing. Somewhere in between  and creating a bash script I thought maybe I could just create a one-liner function at the command line like:

```
numresults(){ ls "$1"/RealignerTargetCreator | wc -l }
```

I've tried a few things like using eval, using `numresults=function...`, but haven't stumbled on the right syntax, and haven't found anything on the web so far. (Everything coming up is just tutorials on bash functions).

Comment: tell me the number of files in the directory `$1/RealignerTargetCreator`.

Comment: you re missing the semicolon at the end. `... ; }`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Quoting [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/521943/158442) for a similar question on Ask Ubuntu:

> Functions in `bash` are essentially named compound commands (or code
>   blocks). From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html):
>
> ```
> Compound Commands
>    A compound command is one of the following:
>    ...
>    { list; }
>           list  is simply executed in the current shell environment.  list
>           must be terminated with a newline or semicolon.  This  is  known
>           as  a  group  command. 
>
> ...
> Shell Function Definitions
>    A shell function is an object that is called like a simple command  and
>    executes  a  compound  command with a new set of positional parameters.
>    ... [C]ommand is usually a list of commands between { and },  but
>    may  be  any command listed under Compound Commands above.
> ```
>
> There's no reason given, it's just the syntax.

Try with a semicolon after `wc -l`:

```
numresults(){ ls "$1"/RealignerTargetCreator | wc -l; }
```

Comment: Well, that was simple! (I mean the semicolon). Again, its always good to get a deeper understanding of how the shell works.

Comment: The semicolon is necessary because `}` is not a control character and does not terminate a command. Notice `echo }` simply outputs the literal string.

Comment: @chepner That's just pushing the question one level down. Those who created the grammar could make `}` special for functions. zsh, for example, has no problems with `foo () {echo foo}`.

Comment: I'm describing what *is*, not what *could be*.

Comment: @chepner And I'm saying it isn't *necessary*, it's just the way the syntax is.

Comment: great that it worked for you guys, for me it just gives  "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' ".  >> bash 4.1.2 on RHEL <<

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `ls | wc -l` as it may give you wrong results if file names have newlines in it. You can use this function instead:

```
numresults() { find "$1" -mindepth 1 -printf '.' | wc -c; }
```

Comment: Thanks. It's always good to deepen one's bash skills! Just curious, how could a file name have a newline in it?

Comment: You can use `touch $'file\nwith\nline'` to create a filename with newlines

Comment: @abalter Yep. That's why it's a mantra: [Don't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 3):

You can also count files without `find`. Using arrays,

```
numresults () { local files=( "$1"/* ); echo "${#files[@]}"; }
```

or using positional parameters

```
numresults () { set -- "$1"/*; echo "$#"; }
```

To match hidden files as well,

```
numresults () { local files=( "$1"/* "$1"/.* ); echo $(("${#files[@]}" - 2)); }
numresults () { set -- "$1"/* "$1"/.*; echo $(("$#" - 2)); }
```

(Subtracting 2 from the result compensates for `.` and `..`.)

Comment: The first of the hidden files functions could use `dotglob`, since it's using arrays anyway.

Comment: Hm, for some reason I remembered `dotglob` matching `.` and `..` as well, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

error if you already have an `alias` with the same name as the function you're trying to define.

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way maybe is echoing what you want to get back.

```
function myfunc()
{
    local  myresult='some value'
    echo "$myresult"
}

result=$(myfunc)   # or result=`myfunc`
echo $result
```

Anyway [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions) you can find a good how-to for more advanced purposes