# Aliasing a command and using it in the same line of code

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I was wondering if you could alias a command, and use it in the same line of code, see this example:

`alias php=/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php; php -v;`

I want this to output PHP 5.6.

`alias php=/opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php; php -v;`

and I want this to output PHP 7.3. However, what I get is this:

```
php -v
# outputs 5.6

alias php=/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php; php -v;
# outputs 5.6

alias php=/opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php; php -v;
# outputs 5.6

php -v
# outputs 7.3
```

I've tried the `&&` operator but it has the same outcome.

I'm wanting to use this in a gitlab continuous integration script, which executes a script through `ssh -t` by passing a string. However I am calling several php functions and I dont want to paste the full php path every time:

`ssh -v -tt $SSH_HOST_NAME "__my_php_commands_here__"`

Comment: `a gitlab continuous integration script` batch shells don't support aliases (by default). Just `php() { command /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php "$@"; }`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the command line is being parsed, and aliases applied, before anything is executed.  However, you can do it with shell functions.  I don't have PHP, but I have several Perl versions to test with:

```
$ perl -v |grep version                      #  V
This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 2 (v5.26.2) built for x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi

$ perl(){ /usr/bin/perl "$@" ; } ; perl -v |grep version
This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 3 (v5.26.3) built for x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi
                                             #  ^
```

So defining the pass-through function

```
perl(){ /usr/bin/perl "$@" ; }
```

changes how the word `perl` is interpreted later in the command line.  Note that you do need the `;` before `}` — see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35466236/2877364).

For your use case, I would recommend using a different name to avoid confusion.  E.g.:

```
currphp(){ /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php "$@" ; } ; currphp -v
currphp(){ /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php "$@" ; } ; currphp -v
```

Answer (score 2):

> in a gitlab continuous integration script

Batch non-interactive shells don't support aliases (by default). And that's a good think. `alias` should be just used as your own, custom shorthand, not in batch scrips.

You could

a) define a function with the same name and use full path for command resolution:

```
php() { /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php "$@"; }
php -v
```

Downsides: function are not exported, unless you add `export -f php`, it is a shell function. Something like `xargs php` will work incorrectly.

b) use a varaible.

```
php=/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php
"$php" -v
```

Downside: you have to modify all scripts and always check out for the `$php`.

c) Modify the path, so your php is found first. You could create a temporary directory and add it to path:

```
tmpd=$(mktemp -d)
trap 'rm -r "$tmpd"' EXIT
ln -s /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php "$tmpd"/php
export PATH="$tmpd"/php:$PATH
php -v
```

If you `export PATH` correctly, it will work everywhere. Remember to remove the folder tho.

Side note: You don't "alias a variable", you "alias a command". `alias` allows you to substitute the first (and only the first) word in a simple command. `php` is a command.

Answer (score 1):

I've went with a `.bashrc` solution. I initially started with this but for some reason the aliases werent being picked up. It appears you need to set a custom `expand_aliases` setting.

My .bashrc ended up looking like this:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases;

alias php=/opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php;
alias composer=/usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/composer.phar;
```

This seemed to do the trick and gave me the correct PHP version while using `ssh xx@1.2.3.4 "php -v"`.